# How to manually write a typescript declaration file?

Tags: typescript

I have a function that was written in javascript:

```
function myFunction(param1, param2) {
//do stuff
}
```

How would I write a typescript declaration file to make sure that param1 is a string that contains {} and param2 is either a number, string, or array of numbers/strings?

For example:

```
param 1 = "The boat is {}"
param 2 = "yellow"
```

Example2:

```
param1: "There are {} out of {} students here"
param2: [20, 30]
```

Param2 should have exactly the number of elements corresponding to the number of "{}". Param1 must contain at least 1 {}. Return type should be a String

Comment: Like [this](//tsplay.dev/weQ6Kw) maybe? You haven't mentioned the return type, nor have you specified if `param2` needs to have exactly the number of elements corresponding to the number of `"{}"` strings in the input, so I assume it doesn't return anything and we're not trying to enforce such a restriction.  Also caring about the contents of strings means you *could* find it hard to use the function, an arbitrary `string` will be rejected.  Anyway if this meets your needs I could write up an answer; if not, let me know what's missing (and [edit] the question to demonstrate missed use cases).

Comment: My apologies, you're correct. I've added the missing restrictions, which as you mentioned are that param2 should have exactly the number of elements corresponding to the number of {} and the return type should be String. Yes, an arbitray string should be rejected if it doesn't have the {}

Comment: So then does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WY3LdN) meet your needs?  (Aside:  [`String` is probably not what you mean](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#number-string-boolean-symbol-and-object), so I've changed it to `string`.)  If that works I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the approach I'd take if I really wanted to try to enforce these constraints at the type level:

```
declare function myFunction<S extends `${string}{}${string}`>(
    param1: S, param2: Param2<S>
): string;

type Param2<S extends string, A extends any[] = []> =
    S extends `${string}{}${infer R}` ?
    Param2<R, [...A, number | string]> :
    A | (A extends [any] ? A[0] : never);
```

So `myFunction` is [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in `S`, the type of the `param1` parameter, which is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to the "pattern [template literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types)" (as implemented and defined in [microsoft/TypeScript#40598](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40598)) `` `${string}{}${string}` ``, which corresponds to all strings known to contain at least one occurrence of the string `"{}"`.  Then the type of `param2` is `Param2<S>`, the intent of which is to represent the correct type of `param2` corresponding to `param1`.  And `myFunction()` returns a `string`.

The `Param2<S>` type is a [tail-recursive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html#tail-recursion-elimination-on-conditional-types) that essentially counts the number of `"{}"` occurrences in `S` and produces a [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) of exactly that length whose elements are all `string | number` (a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) that accepts either `string` or `number` values)... and futhermore, if that length is `1`, it also accepts a bare `string | number`.

The way it works is to accumulate the result in a tuple type parameter `A` which starts off as the empty tuple `[]`.  If `S` has a `"{}"` in it, then we compute `Param2<R, [...A, number | string]>` which is the same operation acting on the part of the string `R` after the first `"{}"`, and with another `number | string` element appended to `A` (via [variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types)).  If `S` has no `"{}"` in it, then we're done and we can return the accumulated `A`... and if `A` is of length `1`, then we also produce a union of `A` with `number | string`.

---

Let's test it.  The following calls compile with no error:

```
myFunction("The boat is {}", "yellow");
myFunction("The boat is {}", ["yellow"]);
myFunction("There are {} out of {} students here", [20, 30]);
myFunction("There are {} out of {} students here and the boat is {}", [20, 30, "yellow"]);
```

while the following calls all have at least one error:

```
myFunction("The boat is yellow", []) // error! 
// ------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Argument of type '"The boat is yellow"' is not assignable to 
// parameter of type '`${string}{}${string}`'

myFunction("The boat is {}", ["yellow", "green"]); // error! 
// -----------------------------------> ~~~~~~~
// Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.

myFunction("There are {} out of {} students here", 20); // error! 
// ----------------------------------------------> ~~
// Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to 
// parameter of type '[string | number, string | number]'

myFunction("There are {} out of {} students here", [20, 30, 40]); // error! 
// ----------------------------------------------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Source has 3 element(s) but target allows only 2
```

That all makes sense.  In the first case `param1` doesn't have even a single `"{}"` in it, so it's an error.  In the rest of the cases, `param2` has either too many or too few elements.

---

So there you go, that's what you've asked for.  Note that this *might* be more trouble than it's worth, depending on your use cases.  It's a fairly complicated bit of typing, and it requires the compiler keep track of the exact [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of the value you pass in for `param1`.  TypeScript will often take string literals and widen their types to just `string` since heuristically speaking people often don't care about literal types.  For example:

```
let someString = "The boat is {}";
// let someString: string;
```

Here I've used `let`, which prompts the compiler to widen the variable to `string` assuming I might re-assign it later.  Then you write this and get an error:

```
myFunction(someString, "yellow"); // error!
// Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to 
// parameter of type '`${string}{}${string}`'
```

Even though this would be fine at runtime, the compiler complains; it has forgotten what value is in `someString` and therefore cannot be sure it has a `"{}"` in it.  Maybe that's fine for your use cases, but you should be aware that it has the potential to be quite annoying to use.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgJzgWwEwB4DKUIA9gQB2AJgM5SnAICWhA5gDRQCCO+RZUchIA2gLpQAvFAEA+YVGx4CJcgAMAJAG9KNegF9lGlbQBmEBFABKG+QFgAUFBtQA-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-f8Tww41sMzBsczbcix1TPUAjgY1TXNS1x0sOcqyg2tcMHMjEzcGkoDTQwECaBAAEIxzTABaAzDIkAA-UyzPMiyLMElgEDofxD0Y0BICgAByR9+x48hFMlFzB0IJoQzgUhSGoOhCDgAJ7SwpoSXWJFgm3LDwGgFzhmBLQdBGR4zBcrVpMgr13PksNm1EVs80jSU6ERIgKLVVS9XUzSdOswy2vajrOq6gyTMs6zvWS1zgV8sN-MC4LQvCyLoGAGKnJS2oDz0WgIGIFz3DyysCsXdDYLXBjEqQ5FWLQxFIwveq1P+ZrdL1br7oex62t66y-js5AHMS+bXLBQwRvIMauAmsKIqi2bYpQeKjC+waXN4YFPn8cEmAR0EkcMfhcsk-LPR22joH2j9Do0H9UIAp8zyIpiSIAFlvI4Gpwa7tNuqAnvZjnnqgSy+u7KQNwQJkAKCpicHtD6-0SUgiQCD9gEQOgkS4PNyBaEUQCgVAtSse0Q1tD75WhEQioHEqIyoqBdYoJoDfeKFInVKwcZufWIENyImHKkdLsa5mtNe2z7L-RzYeGvyAqBkKQem6KIY+ghoZ3b7Uomd4MtT7L5BcoA)